# Ошибка в запросе MySQL: "You have an error in your SQL syntax..."

Tags: mysql

Прошу прощения, если вопрос дилетанта. Пишу запрос на My SQL.

Есть две таблицы:

- Одна таблица "пользователь - друг" `user_fr` (две колонки `id_user` и `id_friend`) хранит связи между пользователями ПО и его друзьями.
- Вторая таблица "пользователь - организация" `user_org` (две колонки `id_user` и `id_org`) хранит связи между пользователем и компанией, где этот пользователь работает.

Есть задача выбрать все организации, где работают друзья пользователя или друзья друзей пользователя.
У меня получился вот такой запрос:

```
select distinct id_org from user_org where id_user in 
(
(select distinct id_friend from user_fr where id_user in 
(select distinct id_friend from user_fr where id_user = AAAAAAAA) and id_friend <> AAAAAAAA) 
union 
(select distinct id_friend from user_fr where id_user = AAAAAAAA )
)
```

Почему-то получаю ошибку:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'union (select distinct id_friend from user_fr where id_user
>   = AAAAAAAA and ' at line 1

Comment: как минимум AAAAAAAA  должны быть в кавычках, и в добавок ко всему Вы выложили не полный запрос, а лишь его часть. А дважды вложенный селект.. брррр...

Comment: У вас неправильно расставлены скобки.

Comment: скобки то верно расставлены как раз таки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас слишком много in и слишком много distinct...

```
select distinct id_org
from
user_org uo join 
  ( select id_friend from user_fr where id_user = 'AAAAA'
    union all
    select u2.id_friend
      from user_fr u1 
        join user_fr u2 on u1.id_friend = u2.id_user
      where u1.id_user = 'AAAAA' and u2.id_friend <> 'AAAAA') fff
  on uo.id_user = fff.id_friend
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct `id_org` from `user_org` where `id_user` in 
(
(select distinct `id_friend` from `user_fr` where `id_user` in 
(select distinct `id_friend` from `user_fr` where `id_user` = "AAAAAAAA") and `id_friend` <> "AAAAAAAA") 
union 
(select distinct `id_friend` from `user_fr` where `id_user` = "AAAAAAAA" )
)
```

Мне одному кажется, что запрос странный?

Comment: Странный..? Скорее страшный..